# Change attribute min of input type=date in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have two input fields of type date.

```
<input id="startdate" type="date" min='@DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString()' onchange="handler(event)" />
<input id="enddate" type="date" min="@DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToShortDateString()" onchange="handler(event)" />
```

I want in enddate min date be alaways two days ahead towards selected date in start date. So far I use script adding days and selecting attribute min.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function handler(e) {
            var someDate = new Date($("#startdate").val());
            document.getElementById("enddate").setAttribute('min', addDays($("#startdate").val(),2));
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addDays(date, days) {
            var result = new Date(date);
            result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
            return result;
        }
    </script>
```

This proposition is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Use a conditional validation attribute (e.g. a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreaterThan]` attribute so you get both client and server side validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using moment.js

```
<input id="startdate" type="date" min='' />
<input id="enddate" type="date" min="" />

<!-- import moment.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function(){
  $('#startdate').attr('min', moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'))

  $('#startdate').on('change', function(e){
    var startDate = $(this).val();
    var endDate = moment(startDate).add(2, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    $('#enddate').attr('min', endDate);
  })
})()
</script>
```

Comment: Do I have put addtional import connected with moment.js?

Comment: Yes. You need to include moment.js

Comment: <script src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script> is enough in head section?